# Why does parseInt() return an unexpected result when I pass a string with a leading zero?

Tags: javascript

`parseInt('1') = 1`
`parseInt('01') = 1`
`parseInt('5') = 5`
`parseInt('05') = 5`
`parseInt('8') = 8`

But why:
`parseInt('08') = 0`
`parseInt('09') = 0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Always use the overload that takes the radix as the second parameter:

```
parseInt('011',10) = 11
```

Answer (score 9):

here is a hint:

```
parseInt('011') = 9
```

If it's starting with 0 it's parsed as an octal number.

Answer (score 8):

Numbers start with `0`(not `0x`) are octal numbers. Therefore `8` and `9` are not a valid octal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When converting a string into decimal number in JavaScript, you may use the plus operator instead parseInt or parseFloat, like in this example:

x = +("12"); // to x is assigned a number 12, after its conversion from a string "12"

x = +("1" + "2"); // to x is assigned a number 12, after its conversion from a string "12"

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered why part.

To remove, you can use `parseFloat`() or parseInt(value, base)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/HsrDx/)