# JS parseInt() returning 0

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why parseInt() works like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444980/why-parseint-works-like-this)

I have an issue with parseInt() returning 0 unexpectedly, here's a sample:

```
parseInt('-06') = -6
parseInt('-07') = -7
parseInt('-08') = 0
```

Why is the result 0? Same if I keep going down (-09, -10, ect). The format of the string comes from my framework so I need to deal with it. Thanks!

Comment: What browser is this behavior occurring in? Works just fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: Ahhh, it happens in IE just for reference.

Comment: @MatthewCox And in Fire Fox, as you can see by running this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NTyMY/2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass a radix parameter when you use `parseInt`

```
parseInt('-08', 10);
```

When you don't, and when the string you're parsing has a leading zero, `parseInt` produces different results depending on your browser.  The most common issue is that the string will be treated as a base-8 number, which is what you're seeing.

That's why this worked for '-06' and '-07'—those are both valid base-8 numbers.  Since '-08' isn't a valid base-8 number, the parse failed, and 0 was returned.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> radix
>
> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned
>   string. While this parameter is optional, always specify it to
>   eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior.
>   Different implementations produce different results when a radix is
>   not specified.

---

Also note that you can use the unary `+` operator to convert these strings to numbers:

```
​var str = '-08';
var num = +str;

console.log(num);​​​

//logs -8
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XAdWH/)

Comment: _"parseInt assumes the number you're parsing is base 8."_ - Even worse, this behaviour is not consistent across browsers.

Comment: @nnn - indeed - the MDN link said the same thing.  I had no idea this was undefined behavior.

Comment: I just put together a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NTyMY/2/) to test this  out. I don't have IE on my home computer, but the string is treated as base 8 in FireFox and as base 10 in Chrome.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut - ha - just tested this myself.  I didn't know Chrome did that.  Another reason to love Chrome, I guess

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response! You rock!

Comment: @KM - my pleasure - Stack Overflow is quite addicting :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this:

```
'-06' * 1 = -6
'-07' * 1 = -7
'-08' * 1 = -8
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in `firefox`, use `parseFloat` instead .get more detaile about this bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507993).

check `parseFloat` result [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U6tTb/).

Comment: It's not really a bug per se - the language specification changed how `parseInt()` was supposed to work when no radix is specified, so browsers that still do it the old way aren't too crazy. Note that you can't just substitute `parseFloat()` and get the same result, not if the input might be something like `"123.45"`.